# How to make div disappear when scrolling

Tags: html, css

Could someone help me make a div disappear when as it scrolls?

For example, if I have a simple header and a bunch of paragraphs below and I scroll, I want the header to stay fixed at the top and the paragraphs below it to scroll past and disappear beneath the header. So far I have tried the following:

https://jsfiddle.net/5k8u9w9t/2/

basically, I set the header's styling to `position: fixed`, but the paragraphs are not disappearing below it. Can someone help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will tidy it up...

```
.container1 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  z-index: 1;
}

.container2 {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 80px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you are trying to do, but maybe this answers your question:

```
.container1 {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #fff;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {margin:0;}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.navbar a:hover {
  background: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.main {
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  height: 1500px; /* Used in this example to enable scrolling */
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div>

<div class="main">
  <h1>Fixed Top Menu</h1>
  <h2>Scroll this page to see the effect</h2>
  <h2>The navigation bar will stay at the top of the page while scrolling</h2>

  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
  <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```